# Share folders between host and container in docker for Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, docker

I'm using the lastest [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/#docker-for-windows), which needs Hyper-V to be enabled, and virtualbox cannot be used in this case.

I've installed the the *ubuntu* container and started it, I want to mount `C:\Users\username` in the docker container. I've tried the following methods.

1. `docker run -t -i -v /c/Users/username:/mnt/c ubuntu /bin/bash`
2. `docker run -d -P --name windows -v C:\Users\username:/mnt/c ubuntu /bin/bash`
3. `docker run -t -i -v /c/Users/username:/mnt/c ubuntu /bin/bash`

None of them worked. I noticed that `/mnt/c` was created automatically, but it contained nothing.

Given that `Docker for Windows` is pretty new, most information I found online was about `Boot2Docker` or `virtualbox`, which is useless to me.

Comment: `-v /Users/username:/whatever`?

Comment: Maybe you should create that folder first in your `Dockerfile` (`FROM ubuntu
RUN mkdir /mnt/c`).